# Simple Rails text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters, formbuilder

I'm trying to understand how a simple text_field_tag works in a specific example that someone is doing. I've read the docs completely on this tag but I'm confused by how it's used here:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
```

In the docs it says, **text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})**. This formula doesn't seem to match what the other person did in the example I showed. Thank you for the help.

Comment: At 4:25 you can see the full example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62UJGZKNiWw

Comment: If you are confused by the number of arguments, by not supplying the options argument it will just use the default value of `{}`.

Comment: I don't think I have a good enough grasp on how exactly the form is being submitted, and how the actual inputted text is being placed into the params hash.

Comment: so in text_field_tag ':search' is the name, and params[:search] is value. now after value. what ever you write. text_field_tag function will make it hash and send as options. mostly we send class, pattern, placeholder in the end. give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I wasn't understanding.

`params[:search]` is getting the value from the *last* request so that the field isn't empty when you're shown the results. Took me a second to figure that out.